# Installation of java in LINUX

Tags: java, redhat-enterprise-linux, rpm

I am trying to install Java on Red Hat Linux through SSH.

I am using `wget` to download the installer. When `wget` downloads the file, it saves it with a filename of

```
jre-6u16-linux-i586-rpm.bin?e=1255431454245&h=f50f4cda5641e55f8e49f217e854faca%2F&filename=jre-6u16-linux-i586-rpm.bin
```

But, when I try to execute the file to install it, it throws this error

```
cannot access `jre-6u16-linux-i586-rpm.bin?e=1255431454245': No such file or directory
```

I am new to Linux. Please explain how to install Java on Linux through the terminal.

Comment: not ssh-related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First and foremost make sure the file is not the webpage, the Linux jre6u16 is roughly 19mb. The ampersand (&) in the filename as already stated, tells the OS to run the process in the background. Rename the file to something simpler using `mv` and put the filename in quotes:

```
mv "jre-6u16-linux-i586-rpm.bin?e=1255431454245&h=f50f4cda5641e55f8e49f217e854faca%2F&filename=jre-6u16-linux-i586-rpm.bin" jre-6u16-linux-i586-rpm.bin
```

then allow execute permissions:

```
chmod a+x jre-6u16-linux-i586-rpm.bin
```

then we can install it:

```
./jre-6u16-linux-i586-rpm.bin
```

Comment: Protip: while wget doesn't typically get the filename right when grabbing URLs with arguments, lftpget and curl usually do the right thing and save the file with the correct name.

Also, "wget -O blah.rpm http://host.name/url/path/blah.rpm" is another way to get it right the first time.

Answer (score 2):

How big is this file (`ls -lh jre*`)? To me, it looks like you've downloaded Sun's download page instead of the installer.

Additionally, there is no such thing as a "Linux OS". (Linux is the kernel, try to become familiar with the terminology!) If your looking for answers, try searching (aka googling) for your distribution name, e.g. "ubuntu java installation" or "suse java installation". You may also try to include your version for even better results, e.g. "karmic java installation".

And finally, you should consider serverfault.com and superuser.com for this kind of questions.

Comment: You are spot on with the "To me, it looks like you've downloaded Sun's download page instead of the installer.part" +1

Comment: wget does that for this kind of download page when the download url goes through a script.  you'd need to specify `-O filename` to save it to `filename`.  looking at the size as the answer suggests will help you figure out if it got the file you expected.

Answer (score 1):

What Linux distribution are you using? Most of them should allow you to install Java through their package management system (such as [APT](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/apt-howto/) for Debian and Ubuntu), which is easier, and allows for easy updates as well.

If you really must install it manually, start by renaming the file to something shorter and then make it executable with this command:

```
chmod a+x filename
```

Then you should be able to run it.

Comment: Yes, I guess its a problem of file execution.

Answer (score 1):

you probably had to put quotes around when you ran wget.

rename the file like this

```
mv 'jre-6u16-linux-i586-rpm.bin?e=1255431454245&h=f50f4cda5641e55f8e49f217e854faca%2F&filename=jre-6u16-linux-i586-rpm.bin' jre-6u16-linux-i586-rpm.bin
```

then install it

Comment: Rename it as gnibbler suggest and make it as executable by chmod +x jre-6u16-linux-i586-rpm.bin and use ./jre-6u16-linux-i586-rpm.bin
to install it

Answer (score 0):

1. Not really programing related,
2. Use quotes around file name (jre-6u....). That ampersand "&" in downloaded file name has special meaning (run process in background)
3. Depending on you linux distro there should be better way (distribution specyfic that takes care of all process and updates).